# how to aggregate sum of a property

Tags: c#, linqpad

How to get a sum of all the results.parent1? I am using linqpad. the dump function puts it in a table but i would like to printed via console.write. How can i achieve the same?

```
void Main()
{
    List<parent> a = new List<parent>();
    a.Add(new parent(2, true));

    a.Add(new parent(3, false));
    a.Add(new parent(4, true));

    List<parent> results = a.FindAll(
    delegate (parent p)
    {
        return p.child1 == true;
    });
    if (results.Count > 0)
    {
        //how do i find the sum of all the results.parent1?
        results.Dump();
        Console.Write("sum of all the results.parent1? ");
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// This file holds all user defined indicator methods.
/// </summary>
public class parent
{
    int v;

    public parent(double d, bool b)
    {
        this.parent1 = d;
        this.child1 = b;
    }

    public double parent1 { get; set; }

    public bool child1 { get; set; }



}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(results.Sum(r => r.parent1))`? Or `.Where` and then `.Sum` on `a`?

Comment: Note that you're not performing any aggregation here, so I'm not sure if what I'm saying is what you're looking for.